# Django Error 403 Forbidden - CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I want to use group and users native from Django to authenticate and get access to features in my website.

The service is running with nginx HTTP. myproject.conf :

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name X.X.X.X;

location /static/ {
    alias /home/ec2-user/app/staticfiles/;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

}

I created a view called login_vew, configured a login.html page and configured settings.py just like this doc (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/) says. But the error persist and I dont know what is the problem.
When I run local with python manage.py runserver works fine with debug=True works.

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from store.models import Product
from store.forms import ProductForm


def login_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('painel')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            try:
                login(request, user)
            except Exception as e:
                messages.error(request, 'Ocorreu um erro ao fazer login. Tente novamente.')
            return redirect('painel')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Usuário ou senha incorretos')
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

login.html:

```
      <div class="card-body text-center">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Usuário:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Senha:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required>
      </div>
      <br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Entrar</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

settings.py:

```
DEBUG = False

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = \[
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
\]

LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/painel'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

MIDDLEWARE = \[
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
\]
```

I tried use this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/

Comment: Can you share the request that your browser makes (you can use the "developers console", right click inspect, go to network, see the POST request, an copy the request data).